# Leaflet map partially loading within React project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, leaflet

I am trying to implement a simple Leaflet map within a react component. For some reason the tiles of the map are not loading or loading in random order. Has anyone else experienced this?

Here's the CodeSandbox of the app:
https://codesandbox.io/s/3qmp8x4131

Here's the code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as L from "leaflet";

export default class Map extends React.Component {
  map = null;
  componentDidMount() {
    var map = (this.map = L.map(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this), {
      minZoom: 2,
      maxZoom: 20,
      layers: [
        L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
          attribution:
            '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'
        })
      ],
      attributionControl: false
    }));

    map.on("click", this.onMapClick);
    map.fitWorld();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (!this.map) return;
    this.map.off("click", this.onMapClick);
    this.map = null;
  }

  onMapClick = () => {
    // Do some wonderful map things...
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="map" />;
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't know about reactjs but this seems like a css problem. Are you sure that you have included the .css file correctly?

Comment: I added a style to set the height and width but the issue persists. Here's a working react example:https://codesandbox.io/s/d9pkyg3mq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You did forget to include Leaflet CSS file.
2. You incorrectly specify your `.map` container height.

**1. Include Leaflet CSS**

Pay attention to how the working example you mention in your comment imports Leaflet assets (in `Map/leaflet.js` file):

```js
import L from 'leaflet'; // Same as `import * as L from 'leaflet'` with webpack
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

Notice that it imports Leaflet CSS file explicitly. When it is missing, your tiles will appear shuffled and spread over your page.

Webpack has a `style-loader` and `css-loader` to correctly manage these CSS assets when they are referred to in a JS file.

**2. Specify the map container height**

In your failing code sample, you specify your `<div class="map">` container with CSS:

```css
.map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Be aware that percentage value is based on the element's parent node value, i.e. in this case 100% of the parent's height.

Your DOM hierarchy is:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="App">
        <div class="map">
```

But you have not specified any height for any of your map container's ancestors (i.e. `html`, `body`, `#root` and `.App`). Since their only child is `.map`, they do not have anything else to increase their size, hence they have 0 height.

And your `.map`'s height is 100% of 0, i.e. 0.

Make sure you also specify a height value for each of these ancestors:

```css
html,
body,
#root,
.App {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Or use an explicit height value for your map container, e.g. in `px`.

Updated CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zn89pkmn83

Comment: Thank you. The missing stylesheet fixed it.